# Layout-spring with different spring constants

Tags: netlogo

[image: The top picture is the material at the time of <code>setup</code> and the bottom picture is at the time of error]

I am trying to use something similar to `layout-spring` to simulate tissue mechanics but I want to change the "spring-constant" of the links according to patch variables i.e. heterogeneous spring-constants for the links. Is there a way to do this using the `layout-spring` primitive? Unfortunately I do not know java which I believe is the source code.

I have also tried to begin coding `layout-spring` using the NetLogo language, but upon testing the code, the nodes are shooting off incorrectly. Below is the relevant code that I have tried.

```
links-own [fx fy k]

turtles-own [dxx dyy]

to setup
ask patches with [(pxcor <= (-20)) and ((abs pycor) < (max-pycor / 2))] [sprout 1]
ask turtles [create-links-to turtles-on neighbors4]

to deform   ; propagate deformation of the material by connecting nodes with springs

ask driver [set heading 90   ;driver is an agentset
            fd .01]
ask pinned [set xcor min-pxcor] ;prevents translation of the entire material ;pinned is an agentset

ask links [set fx (k * (link-length - 1) * sin link-heading) * -1
           set fy (k * (link-length - 1) * cos link-heading) * -1]

 ask not-pinned [set dxx sum [fx] of my-in-links
                 set dyy sum [fy] of my-in-links]

 ask not-pinned [set xcor xcor + dxx
                 set ycor ycor + dyy]

 end
```

This simple bit of code is not working. If I can get this working, perhaps I could then use the patch variables to change the spring-constant of the links (k). But if there is a way to use the `layout-spring` primitive to achieve this, then I would prefer such a method.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Or what do you exactly mean with 'not working' ?

Comment: The node agents are shooting off the page and I am getting an error saying they are outside the world. There appears to be an instability leading to node agents shooting off in a manner that is clearly not deformation of the material.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of the world at the error time?

Comment: As can be seen in the screen shots, the response to the green agents (driver) moving to the right is chaotic. Interestingly enough, decreasing the amount of deformation of each agent during each step appears to resolve the problem. I have replaced the above code with: `set xcor xcor + (dxx * .1)` and the same for the 'y' direction. With this change, the deformation looks reasonable. Perhaps there is some requirement for stability that I am overlooking?

Comment: The thing is you're trying to set coordinates that are beyond the world boundaries, you'll want to control when xcor ycor are higher than max-xcor and max-ycor, perhaps by setting the coordinates to exactly the max-xcor, max-ycor; that should fix your problem.

Comment: I would agree but the nodes are undergoing unrealistic deformation due to some instability in the mathematics. Controlling the max coordinates does not solve the problem of trying to replicate a more realistic deformation. I did some testing, and changing the spring constant (k) of the links can also impose the instability. I will have to look into the stability of the mathematics.  But I am surprised to see that the spring-layout algorithm does not seem cause the same instability issues.